# Are there any ASM compilers?

Tags: assembly, optimization, compiler-construction

I know ASM is generaly run through an assembler and result in a more or less one to one mapping to the final binary but that's not what I'm thinking of.

*Does anyone make a tool that treats ASM (or object files) as a complied language that it can perform the full gamut of optimizations on?* While such a tool might not be particularly useful in and of it's self, it could do things like function inlining from closed source static libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while I agree with [travelboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394609/are-there-any-asm-compilers/4394631#4394631) in that any such 'compiled assembly' language wouldn't be assembly anymore, I have to mention that there are 'recompilers', and JITs whose source language is machine language (not even assembly).

These programs take a bunch of executable code, typically already loaded and ready to execute, and transform it, recognizing a varyiety of constructs and replacing with different versions, which can be better, faster, safer or just different.

qemu is an example of this.  In it's original form is a CPU emulator that works by recompiling from a given CPU binary into a different CPU for execution ([Binary Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation)).  But it can also work when both CPUs are the same, in this case the transformation allows privileged code to execute in a VM environment by 'breaking out' to the hardware emulator.

A *very* interesting example is HP Dynamo ([old Ars Technica article](http://arstechnica.com/reviews/1q00/dynamo/dynamo-1.html)), a research software that achieved unexpected speedups by recompiling HP PA-8000 binaries.

Comment: Neat stuff. Do any of those work in an offline mode? That is a binary-file to binary-file translation rather than a memory-image to memory-image translation?

Comment: That's pretty interesting indeed. Is there also anything like a hardware-independent interchange format?

Comment: @travelboy: none that i know about (but lots of are suggesting that "x86 is the new bytecode").  @BCS: both JVM and CLR are stack-based machines, so they're not like 'real' machine language.  more modern bytecodes are register-based (Lua, new JavaScripts, Dalvik, some Pythons, i think Parrot), making them closer to an assembly language (and with a significant performance advantage)

Comment: There is no particular reason that a synthetic ASM need resemble the real machine. If you JIT it, then the differences disappear and if you don't you will take a perf hit no matter what it looks like.

Comment: stack based machines have quite different 'feel' from machine language.  programming those is far closer to Forth or PostScript than to assembler.

Comment: I'll stand by my previous comment. The feel of something that isn't intended for human production/consumption is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @BCS: i guess that's just a matter of opinion and names.  for me, very few bytecodes can be called 'assembly'. specially stack-based ones. for others (and it seems that includes you) any linearly-executable binary  (as opposed to executable syntax trees, such as used by Perl) can be.

Answer (score 3):

Think of ASM and machine code as two different forms of expressing the same information (instructions). The output of a compiler is machine code. ASM is that already (only written in a human readable form), so a compiler wouldn't have much to do.

There are tools for assembly language that let you define macros or that do register allocation for you, but anything more advanced would be considered a compiler and its input not assembly language anymore.

Comment: I am and was fully aware of all of that. That said, there is no reason that you can't treat ASM as a "higher" level language, or more likely as intermediate code. Extract the basic block structure and you can even do things like loop unrolling and dead code elimination (admittedly not very useful unless you do it after inlineing a function so you have more context than the original compiler).

Comment: Oh, and I'm being a bit sloppy by mostly ignoring the difference between ASM and machine code.

Comment: Now I see what you mean… I guess assembly code is usually regarded as a final product, so optimizations such as loop unrolling would occur in an earlier step (few humans program directly in assembly these days…). That doesn't mean it's not possible. I wasn't aware of such tools, but Javier apparently knows more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Art of Assembly language is what you are looking for :
http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/index.html

Answer (score 0):

When DEC made a transition from VAX architecture to AlphaAXP, their MACRO32 assembler became a sort of high-level language compiler targeting Alpha. AFAIR, there've been some optimisations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX_Macro